# Chrome Webdriver Driver.log Empty

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm having some issues getting chrome to give any output in its `driver` log. Firefox works nicely, and the Chrome log exist, however it's empty despite having run the test. Below you can see the myriad of things I have tried to get output from the webdriver.

```
ch_caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
ch_caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
mydrivers = [webdriver.FireFox, webdriver.Chrome]

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_login_logout(self):
        for driver in mydrivers:
            if driver == webdriver.Chrome:
                the_driver = driver(service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=chrome_temp.log"], 
                                    desired_capabilities=ch_caps)
            else:
                the_driver = driver()

            self.doLogIn(the_driver)
            self.doLogOut(the_driver)

            for line in the_driver.get_log('driver'):
                print line
            the_driver.quit()
```